# Unity PlayerPrefs does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, settings

I am getting errors using PlayerPrefs in Unity 4.6. I keep getting the error message saying "PlayerPrefs does not exist in the current context." I get the same message in MonoDevelop when I move the mouse pointer to hover over the PlayerPrefs statement. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It is better if you add the whole code to your question. Not to my answer.

Comment: I tried to do that earlier, but the comment link was not on the page. As it turned out, Unity3d was in some weird state. I closed it out and reopened it, and the problem went away. I have seen this before though.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes Unity3d just breaks and causes weird errors. But it is fixed ones you reopen it. Commenting was probably hidden because it is better practice to edit your own question and add code there. In comments the layout gets messy.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are not in a true context means not in a class extended from `monoBehavious`

your desired code should look like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KiaStart : MonoBehaviour
{
    // you can use PlayerPrefs here!...

    void Start()
    {
        
    }


    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```